# quiero recorrer un array de numeros y cadenas y devolver en otro array solo las cadenas. estoy usando javascript

Tags: javascript

necesito ayuda con una función que me ayude a sacar solo los strings de un arreglo de enteros y cadenas, no se como dar la orden de que busque solo array. ya no se me ocurre nada más y aparte no funciona. :(
saludos.

```
**var arreglo = [ 4, 'Hola', 45, 'Adios' ] ;
function sacarSoloLosStrings(array){
  let nuevoArray = [ ];
  for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    if (array [i]  ===  ' ') nuevoArray.push (array [i])
  }
  return nuevoArray;
} ;
console.log (sacarSoloLosStrings (arreglo) ;**
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Haciendo `array[i]  ===  ' '` solo estás comprobando si el elemento es una cadena con un espacio en blanco.

Tienes que comprobar si el tipo de cada elemento del array es string, para ello, puedes hacer `typeof array[i] === 'string' || array[i] instanceof String`. Y el código quedaría así:

```js
var arreglo = [4, 'Hola', 45, 'Adios'];

function sacarSoloLosStrings(array) {
  let nuevoArray = [ ];
  for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    if (typeof array[i] === 'string' || array[i] instanceof String) nuevoArray.push(array[i])
  }
  return nuevoArray;
}

console.log (sacarSoloLosStrings(arreglo));
```

Comment: Gracias es una manera bastante efectiva. me funciono mucho el typeof, no encontraba como indicar que fuese un string o numero o booleano .

Comment: de nuevo te agradezco

Comment: @MarcoAguilarRomàn la forma de dar las gracias es [marcar la respuesta como válida](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers). Saludos